# AngularJS IComponentOptions

Tags: angularjs

Работая над проектом, столкнулся с такими конструкциями:

```
import * as Constants from '../../../constants';
import Controller from './lesson-schedule.controller';

export const NAME = 'eduLessonSchedule';

const COMPONENT: ng.IComponentOptions = {
    require: {
        headerCtrl: '^^nituHeader'
    },
    controller: Controller,
    templateUrl: Constants.ComponentsPath
    + '/schedule/lesson-schedule/lesson-schedule.template.html'
}

export default {
    Name: NAME,
    Component: COMPONENT
};
```

Не понимаю как работает require, и что такое '^^someText',

еще вот:

```
require: {
        'tabCtrl': '?^nituTab',
        'scheduleCtrl': '?^^eduLessonSchedule'
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

ответ нашел, это подключение контроллера другой компоненты:

https://demisx.github.io/angularjs/directives/2014/11/25/angular-directive-require-property-options.html